# Modify drop down value with preset value

Tags: vue.js

I'm designing a form that can both used to create and edit something.

The form has a dropdown, which isn't initialized when created, but is set with a value when used for editing.

I want to be able to modify the value of the drop down, both for creating & updating, yet is only working when the `mode` is CREATE.

Here's my template:

```
<template>
    <v-row justify="center">
        <v-form ref="form" v-model="valid" lazy-validation>
            <v-text-field v-model="title" label="Title*" :rules="rules.fieldRules" prepend-icon="mdi-text">
            </v-text-field>
            <v-text-field v-model="website_link" label="URL" prepend-icon="mdi-web">
            </v-text-field>
            <h3>Description</h3>
            <text-editor @update:modelValue="getValue" :rules="rules.fieldRules" :modelValue="description">
            </text-editor>
            <br />
            <v-select v-model="selectedState" :readonly="false" :items="items" filled label="Which state?*" prepend-icon="mdi-help"></v-select>
            <v-file-input v-model="files" prepend-icon="mdi-camera" multiple label="File input"></v-file-input>
            <v-layout v-for="file of files" :key="file">
                <v-img :src="generateUrl(file)" max-width="10%" max-height="10%">
                </v-img>
            </v-layout>
            <v-combobox v-model="tags" prepend-icon="mdi-lightbulb" label="Tags" chips clearable multiple filled
                rounded></v-combobox>
            <v-btn :disabled="mode == 'EDIT' ? false : !valid" color="success" class="mr-4" @click="validate">
                Validate
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn color="blue" class="mr-4" @click="backToProfile">
                Back
            </v-btn>
        </v-form>
    </v-row>
</template>
```

`selectedState` is a computed method described as below here:

```js
selectedState: {
            get() {
                if (this.mode == 'CREATE') {
                    return this.state
                } else {
                    const state = this.items.filter((item) => item.value = this.currentConcept.state)[0].title;
                    this.setState(state);
                    return this.state;
                }
            },
            set(value) {
                console.log(`value: ${value}`)
                this.state = value;
            }
        }
```

Am I missing something?

TIA

Comment: What do you expect when you say- `I want to be able to modify the value of the drop down`?

Comment: Try to generalize your `selectedState's get function` to debug the error. Like this- 

```
if (this.mode == "EDIT") {
 const state = this.items.filter(
  (item) => (item.value = this.currentConcept.state),
 )[0].title;
 this.setState(state);
}
return this.state;

```